# resize and Crop image with intervention/image

Tags: laravel, image-processing, intervention

I want to resize crop image like below :

[image]

if image is lower than 500x400, scale up and crop,
also if image is higher, scale down and crop.

i used some `resize, canvas, fit` and other functions but getting some confused at all.

I see users try to reach this post to find answer and i write here the comment:

thanks @snapey , it's my bad in coding, and `->fit()` is doing that without any check, i used fit after some changes to image and so final result is get unexpected, but without any modify, fit works fine like expected.

---

@Snapey answer is correct, I'm using the same code, but my problem is that I modified the image before reaching this code and because of that, I'm getting unexpected results.

Comment: Trying to get the same result

Comment: @RodrigoAzevedo my problem solved,  just use fit, make sure you are not modify image before fit action. also don't use actions consecutively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to test the dimensions to check if the photo is tall or wide, and then fit, crop ore resize as required.

for example

```
        if($img->height() > $img->width()) {
            $img->resize(80,null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
        } else {
            $img->resize(null,80, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
        }
```

in this case, the resize specifies only one constraint and the other is set automatically using the aspect ratio constraint

Comment: thanks @snapey , it's my bad in coding, and fit is doing that without any check, i used fit after some changes to image and so final result is get unexpected, but without any modify, fit works fine like expected, pls change your code to fit, without any if, so i will tick for answer.